# jQuery Multiple Image Upload with Preview and Delete

Tags: jquery, image, file-upload, cross-browser, data-transfer

At the time of image selection, if we select 1 or more images (1.jpeg, 2.jpeg) and close the dialog box and again open to select more files (3.jpeg, 4.jpeg) and close the dialog again then the preview is showing the previous and new images (1.jpeg, 2.jpeg, 3.jpeg, and 4.jpeg) which is OK in GoogleCrome,

**but in Firefox it works only first selection, select more images or delete one image it got empty array.**

**After some tests, I've found out that everything is working fine, but just in Chrome. This error only occours in Edge. In Firefox, it just won't work, but also does not throw any error. In Safari, does not work either.**

The full repository is: https://github.com/christianbayer/image-uploader

**This is the js Plugin **

(function ($) {

```
$.fn.imageUploader = function (options) {

    // Default settings
    let defaults = {
        preloaded: [],
        imagesInputName: 'images',
        preloadedInputName: 'preloaded',
        label: 'Drag & Drop files here or click to browse',
        extensions: ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif', '.svg'],
        mimes: ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/svg+xml'],
        maxSize: undefined,
        maxFiles: undefined,
    };

    // Get instance
    let plugin = this;

    // Will keep the files
    let dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();

    // The file input
    let $input;

    // Set empty settings
    plugin.settings = {};

    // Plugin constructor
    plugin.init = function () {

        // Define settings
        plugin.settings = $.extend(plugin.settings, defaults, options);

        // Run through the elements
        plugin.each(function (i, wrapper) {

            // Create the container
            let $container = createContainer();

            // Append the container to the wrapper
            $(wrapper).append($container);

            // Set some bindings
            $container.on("dragover", fileDragHover.bind($container));
            $container.on("dragleave", fileDragHover.bind($container));
            $container.on("drop", fileSelectHandler.bind($container));

            // If there are preloaded images
            if (plugin.settings.preloaded.length) {

                // Change style
                $container.addClass('has-files');

                // Get the upload images container
                let $uploadedContainer = $container.find('.uploaded');

                // Set preloaded images preview
                for (let i = 0; i < plugin.settings.preloaded.length; i++) {
                    $uploadedContainer.append(createImg(plugin.settings.preloaded[i].src, plugin.settings.preloaded[i].id, true));
                }

            }

        });

    };

    let createContainer = function () {

        // Create the image uploader container
        let $container = $('<div>', {class: 'image-uploader'});

        // Create the input type file and append it to the container
        $input = $('<input>', {
            type: 'file',
            id: plugin.settings.imagesInputName + '-' + random(),
            name: plugin.settings.imagesInputName + '[]',
            accept: plugin.settings.extensions.join(','),
            multiple: 'multiple'
        }).appendTo($container);

        // Create the uploaded images container and append it to the container
        let $uploadedContainer = $('<div>', {class: 'uploaded'}).appendTo($container),

            // Create the text container and append it to the container
            $textContainer = $('<div>', {
                class: 'upload-text'
            }).appendTo($container),

            // Create the icon and append it to the text container
            $i = $('<i>', {class: 'iui-cloud-upload'}).appendTo($textContainer),

            // Create the text and append it to the text container
            $span = $('<span>', {text: plugin.settings.label}).appendTo($textContainer);


        // Listen to container click and trigger input file click
        $container.on('click', function (e) {
            // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
            prevent(e);

            // Trigger input click
            $input.trigger('click');
        });

        // Stop propagation on input click
        $input.on("click", function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

        // Listen to input files changed
        $input.on('change', fileSelectHandler.bind($container));

        return $container;
    };


    let prevent = function (e) {
        // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    };

    let createImg = function (src, id, preloaded) {

        // Create the upladed image container
        let $container = $('<div>', {class: 'uploaded-image'}),

            // Create the img tag
            $img = $('<img>', {src: src}).appendTo($container),

            // Create the delete button
            $button = $('<button>', {class: 'delete-image'}).appendTo($container),

            // Create the delete icon
            $i = $('<i>', {class: 'iui-close'}).appendTo($button);


        // If the image is preloaded
        if (preloaded) {

            // Set a identifier
            $container.attr('data-preloaded', true);

            // Create the preloaded input and append it to the container
            let $preloaded = $('<input>', {
                type: 'hidden',
                name: plugin.settings.preloadedInputName + '[]',
                value: id
            }).appendTo($container)

        } else {

            // Set the index
            $container.attr('data-index', id);

        }

        // Stop propagation on click
        $container.on("click", function (e) {
            // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
            prevent(e);
        });

        // Set delete action
        $button.on("click", function (e) {

            // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
            prevent(e);

            // Get the parent element
            let $parent = $container.parent();

            // If is not a preloaded image
            if ($container.data('preloaded') === true) {

                // Remove from preloaded array
                plugin.settings.preloaded = plugin.settings.preloaded.filter(function (p) {
                    return p.id !== id;
                });

            } else {

                // Get the image index
                let index = parseInt($container.data('index'));

                // Update other indexes
                $parent.find('.uploaded-image[data-index]').each(function (i, cont) {
                    if (i > index) {
                        $(cont).attr('data-index', i - 1);
                    }
                });

                // Remove the file from input
                dataTransfer.items.remove(index);

                // Update input files
                $input.prop('files', dataTransfer.files);
            }

            // Remove this image from the container
            $container.remove();

            // If there is no more uploaded files
            if (!$parent.children().length) {

                // Remove the 'has-files' class
                $parent.parent().removeClass('has-files');

            }

        });

        return $container;
    };

    let fileDragHover = function (e) {

        // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
        prevent(e);

        // Change the container style
        if (e.type === "dragover") {
            $(this).addClass('drag-over');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('drag-over');
        }
    };

    let fileSelectHandler = function (e) {

        // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
        prevent(e);

        // Get the jQuery element instance
        let $container = $(this);

        // Get the files as an array of files
        let files = Array.from(e.target.files || e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);

        // Will keep only the valid files
        let validFiles = [];

        // Run through the files
        $(files).each(function (i, file) {
            // Run the validations
            if (plugin.settings.extensions && !validateExtension(file)) {
                return;
            }
            if (plugin.settings.mimes && !validateMIME(file)) {
                return;
            }
            if (plugin.settings.maxSize && !validateMaxSize(file)) {
                return;
            }
            if (plugin.settings.maxFiles && !validateMaxFiles(validFiles.length, file)) {
                return;
            }
            validFiles.push(file);
            console.log(validFiles);
        });

        // If there is at least one valid file
        if (validFiles.length) {
            // Change the container style
            $container.removeClass('drag-over');

            // Makes the upload
            setPreview($container, validFiles);
        } else {

            // Update input files (it is now empty due to a default browser action)
            $input.prop('files', dataTransfer.files);

        }
    };

    let validateExtension = function (file) {

        if (plugin.settings.extensions.indexOf(file.name.replace(new RegExp('^.*\\.'), '.')) < 0) {
            alert(`The file "${file.name}" does not match with the accepted file extensions: "${plugin.settings.extensions.join('", "')}"`);

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    };

    let validateMIME = function (file) {

        if (plugin.settings.mimes.indexOf(file.type) < 0) {
            alert(`The file "${file.name}" does not match with the accepted mime types: "${plugin.settings.mimes.join('", "')}"`);

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    };

    let validateMaxSize = function (file) {

        if (file.size > plugin.settings.maxSize) {
            alert(`The file "${file.name}" exceeds the maximum size of ${plugin.settings.maxSize / 1024 / 1024}Mb`);

            return false;
        }

        return true;

    };

    let validateMaxFiles = function (index, file) {

        if ((index + dataTransfer.items.length + plugin.settings.preloaded.length) >= plugin.settings.maxFiles) {
            alert(`The file "${file.name}" could not be added because the limit of ${plugin.settings.maxFiles} files was reached`);

            return false;
        }

        return true;

    };

    let setPreview = function ($container, files) {

        // Add the 'has-files' class
        $container.addClass('has-files');

        // Get the upload images container
        let $uploadedContainer = $container.find('.uploaded'),

            // Get the files input
            $input = $container.find('input[type="file"]');

        // Run through the files
        $(files).each(function (i, file) {

            // Add it to data transfer
            dataTransfer.items.add(file);

            // Set preview
            $uploadedContainer.append(createImg(URL.createObjectURL(file), dataTransfer.items.length - 1), false);

        });

        // Update input files
        $input.prop('files', dataTransfer.files);

    };

    // Generate a random id
    let random = function () {
        return Date.now() + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    };

    this.init();

    // Return the instance
    return this;
};
```

}(jQuery));

and 
The HTML file is like that:

```
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" name="name-1" id="name-1">
            <label for="name-1">Name</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" name="description-1" id="description-1">
            <label for="description-1">Description</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field">
            <label class="active">Photos</label>
            <div class="input-images-1" style="padding-top: .5rem;"></div>
        </div>

        <button>Submit and display data</button>

    </form>
```

**and in body tag:
script tag:**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.input-images-1').imageUploader({
            // preloaded: preloaded,
            imagesInputName: 'filesName',
            preloadedInputName: 'old',
            maxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024,
            maxFiles: 4
        });

    });
</script>
```